# Understanding Allen Downey's 'Think Python' Section 5.14 Exercise #1

Tags: python

Link to the exercise can be accessed here - [Section 5.14 Exercise #1](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2006.html#sec68)

Quoting the question:

> Exercise 1
> ...
>
> Write a script that reads the current time and converts it to a time of day in hours, minutes, and seconds, plus the number of days since the epoch.

A possible solution is available here - [Solution](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/issues/18#issuecomment-292769002)

The solution provided above seems easy to understand but I'm confused with the calculations/formulae to convert epoch time to a normal time of day. These lines are confusing me the most:

```
hours = (epoch % seconds_in_a_day) // seconds_in_an_hour + 8
minutes = (epoch % seconds_in_a_day) % seconds_in_an_hour // seconds_in_a_minute
seconds = (epoch % seconds_in_a_day) % seconds_in_an_hour % seconds_in_a_minute
```

My question is, why is the remainder from dividing `seconds_in_a_day` from `epoch` is divided by `seconds_in_an_hour` and then an 8 is added to the result. I've similar confusion with the `minutes` and `seconds` variable as well. I'm trying to understand the logic behind such calculation but it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the epoch is seconds in total since [1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), we only want to observe the amount of seconds elapsed today. This gives the first part of each formula,`(epoch % seconds_in_a_day)`.

Now since we have an amount of seconds that has elapsed today, we can divide it by the amount of seconds in an hour to get the amount of hours. 8 is added here to the result because Beijing's timezone is UTC+8.

Since we also have seconds within a day, for hours and seconds we repeat the logic used for days. If we know that `n` seconds have elapsed since the start of today, we can modulo this time by the amount of seconds in a single hour to get the "remainder" amount of seconds that have elapsed in the last non-complete hour. Now we just divide it by `seconds_in_a_minute` to turn seconds into minutes.

The same logic applies for the seconds.

Comment: Nice! That explains a lot and cleared up a lot of doubts.

Answer (score 2):

I too have been working through the book trying to learn some python coding and today I encountered this question. And here is my attempt,

```
total_secs  = time.time()
seconds = total_secs % 60
minutes = (total_secs // 60) % 60
hours = (total_secs // 3600) % 24
days = total_secs // (3600 * 24)
```

The logic behind this is, the `seconds` is the remainder of total seconds divided by the number of seconds in a minute, and the `minutes` is the remainder of total minutes divided by the number of minutes in an hour, by this logic we can get the `hours` and `days` in the same fashion.

The code is much simpler to read and easier to understand, hopefully it can clear some confusion for the future python beginner who reads this.